# The Star Spangled Shifter and his coded messages

Tags: cipher

I got a strange email today. I tried running this through every decipher I knew of, but I couldn't figure this out. Can you help me figure out what this mysterious figure wants?

> from: thestarspangledshifter@[emailservice].com
> to: Joe-You-Know@[emailservice].com
>
> Subject: 2+star_shift_assistance
>
> Kt''[/ j[[g fpy/
> P d. p, ,ttg [h i[oy dffpfud,btz >i ,d.t pf L[k, Tdj't/ }y[utbu[y [h ukt O,pntftz P d. '[[;p,j h[y ukt ]'dbt rktyt d'' [h ukt ]ytfpgt,uf .ttu/ r[o'g i[o mt dm't u[ kt'] .t [ouX P kdnt o,b[ntytg d .[fu ktp,[of ]'[u u[ gtfu[i ukt ]ytfpgt,uf du 9A== Dz>z [, "dm[y Gdiz }'tdft/ ukt hdut [h uktft .t, ytfu [, i[oz
> Fp,btyt'i/
> L[k, Tdj'tz

Comment: Emails from Star Spangled Shifters and Princes of Nigeria.....may I recommend a much, _much_ stronger spam filter, Joe-You-Know? ;P

Comment: @El-Guest, Like I've mentioned in previous puzzles, my ISP won't let me filter these kinds of emails (no matter what I do)... I think they like to mess with me.

Comment: Joe-You-Know, it appears the fix is in...does your ISP stand for Illuminati Service Provider??

Comment: @El-Guest, They keep telling me that they're not going to take over the world, they promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cipher where it's shifted two keys on a QWERTY keyboard to the right. The translated text is

> Hello, good sir, 
>  I am in need of your assistance. My name is John Eagle, Protector of the Universe. I am looking for the place where all of the presidents meet, would you be able to help me out? I have uncovered a most heinous plot to destroy the presidents at 7:00 AM on Labor Day. Please, the fate of these men rest on you. 
>  Sincerely, 
>  John Eagle

Comment: Besides the punctuation, this is entirely correct. Man, I thought for sure this one was going to be difficult... :|

Comment: It was a good puzzle, and pretty difficult, but r13(gur svefg guerr jbeqf va gur zrffntr znqr zr guvax bs n xrlobneq fuvsg, rfcrpvnyyl jvgu gur pncvgny C.) Fun to solve though!! :D